# csv2geojson.js causing unsupported property error in IE8

Tags: javascript, csv, internet-explorer-8, geojson, mapbox

Demo: http://picturethiswebcenter.com/ods_map/

When I access this map from ie8, it throws an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error on this line of csv2geojson.js,

```
var parsed = (typeof x == 'string') ? dsv(options.delimiter).parse(x) : x;
```

I have been doing a bit of googling but cannot figure what ie8 is missing here, any reason why this line might throw an error?

Comment: Can you make sure the object returned by `dsv(options.delimiter)` has a `parse` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DSV library that csv2geojson.js uses some "build-in" functions that aren't supported in IE8, namely `map` function. Other parts of the code uses `forEach`. I pulled up the following snippet from the DSV code:

```
function dsv(delimiter) {
  var dsv = {},
      reFormat = new RegExp("[\"" + delimiter + "\n]"),
      delimiterCode = delimiter.charCodeAt(0);

  dsv.parse = function(text, f) {
    var o;
    return dsv.parseRows(text, function(row, i) {
      if (o) return o(row, i - 1);
      var a = new Function("d", "return {" + row.map(function(name, i) {
        return JSON.stringify(name) + ": d[" + i + "]";
      }).join(",") + "}");
      o = f ? function(row, i) { return f(a(row), i); } : a;
    });
  };
  ...
```

The `.map` and `.forEach` Array functions are implemented only in JavaScript 1.6 (ECMAScript 5) and higher. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility .

Long story short, if you want it to work in IE, your code will only work in IE9 or higher. Other options is to rewrite DSV library to be compatible.

Comment: Yep, at the moment this is the case. There are probably IE8 compatible CSV libraries out there, and you're welcome to find & integrate one, but the task of supporting IE8 has lost the effort/reward tug of war.

Comment: I was able to get this map working in IE8 by adding the polyfills for [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) provided by the MDN